# Can I not delete my own questions, after answers were posted?

Tags: support, questions, delete

I have some questions that are just sitting there, for which I either don't agree with the answer / it doesn't work for me. Can I not delete a question once someone has posted an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot delete a question if it has answers posted to it that have at least an upvote.

It's disabled because deleting a useful answer to an on topic question deprives the community as a whole.

If the answers do not work or solve your problem, you can comment on them and/or downvote them to signal to other users that the current batch of answers do not fit/work.

Comment: Needs more [sic]